# Spring Cloud Stream partitionKeyExpression wrong calculation

Tags: spring, stream, apache-kafka, cloud, partitioning

I have a Spring Cloud Stream based microservice using Kafka.

I created a kafka topic with 4 partitions.

I configured the following in my yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        SYNC_TABLE:
          content-type: application/json
          partitionKeyExpression: payload.partitionKey
          partitionCount: 4
          destination: ${envTopicPrefix}.LEGACY_TABLE
```

In my code I have my message class that contains (in its superclass) the partitionKey variable:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@ToString(callSuper=true)
public class TransactionResponse extends GeneralOutputMessage{

}
```

---

```
@Data
@ToString
public class GeneralOutputMessage {

    private String operationType;
    private List<String> affectedFields;
    private Object data;
    private String eventId;
    private String eventName;
    private String partitionKey; 
}
```

I am sending the TransactionsResponse object as a message:

```
final TransactionResponse transactionResponse = handler.handleEvent(event);
if (transactionResponse != null) {
    outputChannels.tableSync().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(transactionResponse).build());
    log.info("Message Sent: {}", transactionResponse);
}
```

My expectation is that spring cloud stream would take the key payload.partitionKey, calculate its hashCode() % 4, and send the event to that partition.

However, the logic is completely random. Here are a few examples:

Math.abs("111615631".hashCode()%4) = 1. However, the message is sent to partition number 3.

Math.abs("110019882".hashCode()%4) = 2. However, the message is sent to partition number 0.

Math.abs("943152574".hashCode()%4) = 0. This message *does indeed* get  sent to partition number 0.

Math.abs("943198862".hashCode()%4) = 0. However, *this* message is sent to partition number 2.

I'm using the Dalston.SR1 release train.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Just tried to send the same event with the same partitionKey (but slightly different message body). The message goes to two different partitions even though the partition key is the same. Looks like Spring Cloud Stream ignores the partitionKeyExpression completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was my mistake, I forgot to add the producer: section in the yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        SYNC_TABLE:
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            partitionKeyExpression: payload.partitionKey
            partitionCount: 4
          destination: ${envTopicPrefix}.LEGACY_TABLE
```